# Properties of a Minkowski sum

Tags: functional-analysis

Why is it necessary for one of the sets in the [Minkowski sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) to be bounded (given that both sets are closed) in order that the Minkowski sum be closed?

[***Edit:*** In view of @robjohn 's comment (thanks!), I should perhaps change the question to: "Why is it necessary for one of the sets in the [Minkowski sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) to be bounded (given that both sets are closed) in order to ***guarantee*** that the Minkowski sum be closed?]

Also, what are the conditions for the Minkowski sum to be open?

Thanks.

Comment: Let $A=\{(x,0):x\ge0\}$ and $B=\{(0,x):x\ge0\}$. $A+B=\{(x,y):x,y\ge0\}$ is closed, yet neither $A$ nor $B$ is bounded.

Comment: Thanks, @robjohn. I have edited the question.

Comment: So you are looking for closed $A$ and $B$ so that $A+B$ is not closed. Of course, both $A$ and $B$ must be unbounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A:=\{1,2,3,...\}$ (that is, $\mathbb{N}$, not including 0), and $B:=\{(-k+1/k\mid k\in \mathbb{N}, k\ge 2\}=\{-2+1/2, -3+1/3,-4+1/4,... \}$. Then both $A$ and $B$ are closed (in fact discrete) subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, but the sum $A+B$ includes all numbers of the form $1/k$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}, k\ge 2$, but it does not include 0. Hence $A+B$ is not closed.