# The given set is closed in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $K$ is a non empty closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ , then show that the set {${x+y : x\in K , y\in [1,2]}$} is closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

I know a set will be closed if it contains all it's limit points but not know how to apply this here...

Comment: What is the definition of a limit point that you use? The two answers already posted are correct, one of them very detailed. Could you please indicate which part you do not follow, that needs extra attention (to justify the bounty) and additional explanations?

Comment: This Q has appeared before.  BTW it is common to write $A+B$ for $\{a+b: a\in A\land b\in B\}$ and $a+B$ for $\{a+b:b\in B\}$..... Note that the  sequential compactness of $[0,1]$ in your Answers is crucial.(A sequence in $[0,1]$ has a convergent sub-sequence). For example, if $A=\Bbb N$ and $B=\{-n+\frac {1}{n+1}:n\in \Bbb N\}$, then $A$ and $B$ are closed but not compact, and $0\in \overline {A+B}\setminus (A+B)$ .

Comment: are you aware that every bounded sequence of real numbers has a convergent subsequence? This is perhaps the main element that makes the proof work. The sum considered (in the above comment) is called Minkowski sum, there are many answers if you search, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/80974 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/80800 there are more too https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=minkowski+sum

Comment: This question has been completely answered by gvhl. I wonder what kind of additional attention you are asking for with your bounty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $(z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a convergent sequence in $\{x + y: x \in K, y \in [1, 2]\}$ with limit $z$. By definition for each $z_n$ there exist $x_n \in K$ and $y_n \in [1, 2]$ such that $z_n = x_n + y_n$. Since $[1, 2]$ is compact by Heine-Borel, there must exists a convergent subsequence $(y_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $y_{n_k} \to y \in [1, 2]$. But then $x_{n_k} \to z - y$, i.e. we have a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $K$. But since $K$ is closed, we have that $z - y \in K$.

But now note that $z = (z - y) + y$, where $(z-y) \in K$ and $y \in [1, 2]$. That is, the limit of $(z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is in the form $x + y: x \in K$ and $y \in [1, 2]$, and thus $\{x + y: x \in K, y \in [1, 2]\}$ is closed.

Comment: gvhi. Very nice.

Comment: when you say "convergent sequence in" a given set, do you mean that the elements are in the set, or that the limit is also in the set. This might be a point of confusion (trying to understand why the OP put a bounty)

Comment: @Mirko "convergent sequence in" means the first point that you mentioned, as in that the elements are a member of the set we are talking about.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $z_n$ is a sequence in $S=\{x+y: x\in K, y \in [1,2]\}$ such that $z_n\rightarrow z$. You have to show $z\in S$.

Since $ z\in S$ there are $x_n,y_n$ such that $x_n\in K$ and $ y_n\in [1,2]$ and $z_n = x_n+y_n$. Since $[1,2]$ is closed and bounded, a subsequence $y_{n_k}$ of $y_n$ converges.

Can you finish from here?

Comment: sir ,  are you using a set $A$ is closed if every convergent sequence in $A$ converges to a limit in $A$?

Comment: @SULTAN I'm not using it, but the continuation of the proof the beginning of which I wrote down will. See the answer of gvhl.